# Правка меток не работает

Tags: дефект, метки, описание-метки

Когда открываю редактор меток, появляется сообщение в непонятной кодировке:

РЎР»РёС€РєРѕРј РјРЅРѕРіРѕ РІР°С€РёС… РїСЂР°РІРѕРє Р±С‹Р»Рѕ РѕС‚РєР»РѕРЅРµРЅРѕ.

Comment: У меня нормально открывается.

Comment: Решить не помогу, но могу перевести. Перекодировал из `cp1251` в `utf-8`: "*Слишком много ваших правок было отклонено*"